# Create a string from parts of a file using reference points in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing

I'm looking to create a Perl script that looks at an snmp MIB, pulls out parts of that MIB given reference points, and adds the results into a string.

For example, this a portion of the data I'm working with:

```
      udpOutDatagrams OBJECT-TYPE
          SYNTAX  Counter
          ACCESS  read-only
          STATUS  mandatory
          DESCRIPTION
                  "The total number of UDP datagrams sent from this
                  entity."
          ::= { udp 4 }


      -- the UDP Listener table

      -- The UDP listener table contains information about this
      -- entity's UDP end-points on which a local application is
      -- currently accepting datagrams.

      udpTable OBJECT-TYPE
          SYNTAX  SEQUENCE OF UdpEntry
          ACCESS  not-accessible
          STATUS  mandatory
          DESCRIPTION
                  "A table containing UDP listener information."
          ::= { udp 5 }

      udpEntry OBJECT-TYPE
          SYNTAX  UdpEntry
          ACCESS  not-accessible
          STATUS  mandatory
          DESCRIPTION
                  "Information about a particular current UDP
                  listener."
          INDEX   { udpLocalAddress, udpLocalPort }
          ::= { udpTable 1 }
```

I'm looking to pull out the object names, add a comma, and then the the descriptions :

```
udpOutDatagrams, The total number of UDP datagrams sent from this entity.
udpTable, A table containing UDP listener information.
udpEntry, Information about a particular current UDP listener.
```

There are some reference points that could be used:

1. All names are immediately followed by the string "OBJECT-TYPE".
2. All descriptions are surrounded by double-quotes and immediately follow a line that says "DESCRIPTION"

I've put together a basic frame to handle this.  Just need some advice on the logic that would be used to create name/description strings.

**UPDATE:  Basic script based on the answer by Sinan Ünür.  It can all be done with [this](http://search.cpan.org/~hardaker/SNMP-5.0401/SNMP.pm#___top).**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use SNMP;
$SNMP::save_descriptions = 1;
my $mib = $ARGV[0];
my $object;

&SNMP::addMibDirs("/usr/share/snmp/mibs/allMibs/");
&SNMP::loadModules($mib);
&SNMP::initMib();

foreach my $key ( keys %SNMP::MIB )
{    
  print "$SNMP::MIB{$key}{label}, $SNMP::MIB{$key}{description}, $SNMP::MIB{$key}{objectID}\n"
};
```

Comment: What have you tried? And do you want to write an actual parser, or just throw some quick regexes at the data?

Comment: @amon I'm thinking a parser right now.  It'd accept a file name as an argument & then search through it.  I'm not sure if it makes more sense to add the entire file to a string & then look through that string, or put it in a while loop and look at it line by line (or something else?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using [SNMP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/SNMP)? It gives you a [%SNMP::MIB hash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/SNMP#%SNMP%3a%3aMIB):

> a tied hash to access parsed MIB information. After the MIB has been loaded this hash allows access to to the parsed in MIB meta-data(the structure of the MIB (i.e., schema)). The hash returns blessed references to SNMP::MIB::NODE objects which represent a single MIB attribute. The nodes can be fetched with multiple 'key' formats - the leaf name (e.g.,sysDescr) or fully/partially qualified name (e.g., system.sysDescr) or fully qualified numeric OID.

Comment: No, I honestly didn't think of it.  This might be what I need.  I'll take a look (thank you!)

Comment: Using SNMP works.  I'll put my final script in the original question.  The script here didn't work - using SNMP was actually easier (if you remove the script example, I'll mark this as the answer.)  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions seems the easiest way to go.

Just parse the file looking for the line "OBJECT-TYPE" then take the text before "OBJECT-TYPE" as the name.

After that look for "DESCRIPTION" then look for the text between the quotation marks that occurs right after.

Then repeat!